# packrat restore using old windows binaries - need cran mirror with old windows package binaries

Tags: cran, packrat

I would like to enable packrat::restore() to use Windows binaries. It seems that official CRAN mirrors do not keep old windows package binaries, hence packrat::restore() will compile from source if the snapshotted package version is no longer the most current.

The alternative of using MRAN with a manually defined CRAN snapshot date is sub-optimal as different packages were installed on different dates, hence it is hard to choose just 1 CRAN snapshot date to restore all packages.

Please assist.